# Nonlinear fade on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the following code to adjust the opacity of an element as you scroll past it:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    this = myfadingdiv
    var height = $(this).height();
    var offset = $(this).offset().top;
    var opacity = (height - homeTop + offset) / height;
    $(this).css("opacity", opacity);
});
```

It works great, but it's linear.  A request was made to have it fade "sooner".

I'd like it to behave more like this (sorry for the crude MS Paint).

[image]

I'm definitely not an algebra person.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the formulas of this site: http://gizma.com/easing/

You can calculate the easing in this way:

**The linear tweening**

```
linearTween = function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*t/d + b;
};
```

---

> t = current time

```
var t = $(window).scrollTop() - offset;
t = t < 0 ? 0 : t;
```

The "Current time" start when your div is on top of the page. Before is 0 (the negative values), after the value is positive (the scrolled pixel).

---

> b = start value

*Is 1, your start opacity*

---

> c = change in value

Change the start value of -1 (1-1 = 0 opacity)

---

> d = duration

The time finish when all div is scrolled, the duration is the height of the div

*Now you have all easing functions for create your custom animation*

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $('#scroll').height();
  var offset = $('#scroll').offset().top;

  var opacity;
  //opacity = (height - $(window).scrollTop() + offset) / height;

  var t = $(window).scrollTop() - offset;
  t = t < 0 ? 0 : t;

  opacity = easeOutCirc(t, 1, -1, height);

  $('#scroll').css("opacity", opacity);

});

/* SOME EASING */

linearTween = function(t, b, c, d) {
  return c * t / d + b;
};

easeInQuad = function(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d;
  return c * t * t + b;
};

easeInOutCirc = function(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d / 2;
  if (t < 1) return -c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) - 1) + b;
  t -= 2;
  return c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) + 1) + b;
};

easeOutCirc = function(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d;
  t--;
  return c * Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) + b;
};
```

```css
#scroll {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Sed placerat consequat suscipit. In et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta quis purus non, euismod varius sem. Aenean condimentum
ullamcorper turpis, ac auctor elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus. Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo, at scelerisque ante. Nullam
augue leo, cursus vitae mattis eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a egestas eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat. Integer nec sapien felis.
Aliquam bibendum egestas aliquet. Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id mattis enim. Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse condimentum orci id diam
hendrerit, eu laoreet sem pharetra. Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante. Sed non leo urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum elit.


<div id="scroll">
  Phasellus mattis nulla eget neque dapibus, mattis mollis elit consequat. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut nulla eu augue luctus viverra. Proin dictum rhoncus finibus. Nulla sed luctus libero, eget sollicitudin purus. Ut pharetra quis neque vel vehicula. Curabitur
  fermentum, nibh ac efficitur fringilla, libero augue tempus dolor, in vehicula odio sem in felis. In eu feugiat dui. Aenean est elit, pulvinar sit amet pretium ut, vestibulum non felis. In ullamcorper ullamcorper erat, a aliquam urna finibus et. Curabitur
  lobortis dapibus aliquam. Phasellus fringilla augue eget dui condimentum, ac ultricies ligula sodales. Aenean et nisi ut ante maximus porta. Cras sollicitudin blandit purus, eget varius dui. Donec in metus erat. Morbi eget ex dolor. Aenean tellus turpis,
  suscipit eu eros vel, ornare feugiat nibh. Suspendisse gravida nunc sem. Cras egestas vestibulum sem at convallis. Nunc eu cursus massa, sed aliquam libero. Sed placerat consequat suscipit. In et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse
  at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta quis purus non, euismod varius sem. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper turpis, ac auctor elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus.
  Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo, at scelerisque ante. Nullam augue leo, cursus vitae mattis eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a
  egestas eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat. Integer nec sapien felis. Aliquam bibendum egestas aliquet. Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id
  mattis enim. Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse condimentum orci id diam hendrerit, eu laoreet sem pharetra. Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante.
  Sed non leo urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec ante aliquet, lacinia risus ac, tristique ipsum. Nam porttitor sed orci
  nec volutpat. Etiam finibus enim felis, at lacinia dui tempor at. Sed sem nulla, feugiat sed imperdiet quis, imperdiet nec felis. Nullam eget suscipit tortor. Suspendisse maximus nec sapien id placerat. Cras ullamcorper enim quis blandit sodales. Fusce
  ullamcorper turpis libero, quis facilisis arcu condimentum sit amet. Etiam vitae luctus turpis, sed maximus nisl. Maecenas cursus tellus mattis eros placerat pulvinar. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Aliquam sit amet enim dolor. Ut et nisi quis urna congue rutrum. Phasellus mattis nulla eget neque dapibus, mattis mollis elit consequat. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut nulla eu augue luctus viverra. Proin dictum rhoncus finibus. Nulla sed luctus libero,
  eget sollicitudin purus. Ut pharetra quis neque vel vehicula. Curabitur fermentum, nibh ac efficitur fringilla, libero augue tempus dolor, in vehicula odio sem in felis. In eu feugiat dui. Aenean est elit, pulvinar sit amet pretium ut, vestibulum non
  felis. In ullamcorper ullamcorper erat, a aliquam urna finibus et. Curabitur lobortis dapibus aliquam. Phasellus fringilla augue eget dui condimentum, ac ultricies ligula sodales. Aenean et nisi ut ante maximus porta. Cras sollicitudin blandit purus,
  eget varius dui. Donec in metus erat. Morbi eget ex dolor. Aenean tellus turpis, suscipit eu eros vel, ornare feugiat nibh. Suspendisse gravida nunc sem. Cras egestas vestibulum sem at convallis. Nunc eu cursus massa, sed aliquam libero. Sed placerat
  consequat suscipit. In et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta quis purus non, euismod varius sem. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper
  turpis, ac auctor elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus. Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo, at scelerisque ante. Nullam augue
  leo, cursus vitae mattis eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a egestas eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat. Integer nec sapien felis. Aliquam
  bibendum egestas aliquet. Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id mattis enim. Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse condimentum orci id diam hendrerit,
  eu laoreet sem pharetra. Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante. Sed non leo urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
  nec ante aliquet, lacinia risus ac, tristique ipsum. Nam porttitor sed orci nec volutpat. Etiam finibus enim felis, at lacinia dui tempor at. Sed sem nulla, feugiat sed imperdiet quis, imperdiet nec felis. Nullam eget suscipit tortor. Suspendisse maximus
  nec sapien id placerat. Cras ullamcorper enim quis blandit sodales. Fusce ullamcorper turpis libero, quis facilisis arcu condimentum sit amet. Etiam vitae luctus turpis, sed maximus nisl. Maecenas cursus tellus mattis eros placerat pulvinar. Orci varius
  natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sit amet enim dolor. Ut et nisi quis urna congue rutrum. Phasellus mattis nulla eget neque dapibus, mattis mollis elit consequat. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut nulla eu augue
  luctus viverra. Proin dictum rhoncus finibus. Nulla sed luctus libero, eget sollicitudin purus. Ut pharetra quis neque vel vehicula. Curabitur fermentum, nibh ac efficitur fringilla, libero augue tempus dolor, in vehicula odio sem in felis. In eu feugiat
  dui. Aenean est elit, pulvinar sit amet pretium ut, vestibulum non felis. In ullamcorper ullamcorper erat, a aliquam urna finibus et. Curabitur lobortis dapibus aliquam. Phasellus fringilla augue eget dui condimentum, ac ultricies ligula sodales. Aenean
  et nisi ut ante maximus porta. Cras sollicitudin blandit purus, eget varius dui. Donec in metus erat. Morbi eget ex dolor. Aenean tellus turpis, suscipit eu eros vel, ornare feugiat nibh. Suspendisse gravida nunc sem. Cras egestas vestibulum sem at
  convallis. Nunc eu cursus massa, sed aliquam libero. Sed placerat consequat suscipit. In et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta
  quis purus non, euismod varius sem. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper turpis, ac auctor elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus. Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et
  tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo, at scelerisque ante. Nullam augue leo, cursus vitae mattis eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a egestas eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean
  a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat. Integer nec sapien felis. Aliquam bibendum egestas aliquet. Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id mattis enim. Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis
  risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse condimentum orci id diam hendrerit, eu laoreet sem pharetra. Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante. Sed non leo urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum
  elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec ante aliquet, lacinia risus ac, tristique ipsum. Nam porttitor sed orci nec volutpat. Etiam finibus enim felis, at lacinia dui tempor at. Sed sem nulla, feugiat sed imperdiet
  quis, imperdiet nec felis. Nullam eget suscipit tortor. Suspendisse maximus nec sapien id placerat. Cras ullamcorper enim quis blandit sodales. Fusce ullamcorper turpis libero, quis facilisis arcu condimentum sit amet. Etiam vitae luctus turpis, sed
  maximus nisl. Maecenas cursus tellus mattis eros placerat pulvinar. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sit amet enim dolor. Ut et nisi quis urna congue rutrum.


</div>

Phasellus mattis nulla eget neque dapibus, mattis mollis elit consequat. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut nulla eu augue luctus viverra. Proin dictum rhoncus finibus. Nulla sed luctus libero, eget sollicitudin purus. Ut pharetra quis neque vel vehicula. Curabitur
fermentum, nibh ac efficitur fringilla, libero augue tempus dolor, in vehicula odio sem in felis. In eu feugiat dui. Aenean est elit, pulvinar sit amet pretium ut, vestibulum non felis. In ullamcorper ullamcorper erat, a aliquam urna finibus et. Curabitur
lobortis dapibus aliquam. Phasellus fringilla augue eget dui condimentum, ac ultricies ligula sodales. Aenean et nisi ut ante maximus porta. Cras sollicitudin blandit purus, eget varius dui. Donec in metus erat. Morbi eget ex dolor. Aenean tellus turpis,
suscipit eu eros vel, ornare feugiat nibh. Suspendisse gravida nunc sem. Cras egestas vestibulum sem at convallis. Nunc eu cursus massa, sed aliquam libero. Sed placerat consequat suscipit. In et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse
at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta quis purus non, euismod varius sem. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper turpis, ac auctor elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus.
Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo, at scelerisque ante. Nullam augue leo, cursus vitae mattis eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a egestas
eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat. Integer nec sapien felis. Aliquam bibendum egestas aliquet. Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id mattis enim.
Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse condimentum orci id diam hendrerit, eu laoreet sem pharetra. Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante. Sed non leo
urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec ante aliquet, lacinia risus ac, tristique ipsum. Nam porttitor sed orci nec volutpat.
Etiam finibus enim felis, at lacinia dui tempor at. Sed sem nulla, feugiat sed imperdiet quis, imperdiet nec felis. Nullam eget suscipit tortor. Suspendisse maximus nec sapien id placerat. Cras ullamcorper enim quis blandit sodales. Fusce ullamcorper
turpis libero, quis facilisis arcu condimentum sit amet. Etiam vitae luctus turpis, sed maximus nisl. Maecenas cursus tellus mattis eros placerat pulvinar. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam
sit amet enim dolor. Ut et nisi quis urna congue rutrum. Phasellus mattis nulla eget neque dapibus, mattis mollis elit consequat. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut nulla eu augue luctus viverra. Proin dictum rhoncus finibus. Nulla sed luctus libero, eget sollicitudin
purus. Ut pharetra quis neque vel vehicula. Curabitur fermentum, nibh ac efficitur fringilla, libero augue tempus dolor, in vehicula odio sem in felis. In eu feugiat dui. Aenean est elit, pulvinar sit amet pretium ut, vestibulum non felis. In ullamcorper
ullamcorper erat, a aliquam urna finibus et. Curabitur lobortis dapibus aliquam. Phasellus fringilla augue eget dui condimentum, ac ultricies ligula sodales. Aenean et nisi ut ante maximus porta. Cras sollicitudin blandit purus, eget varius dui. Donec
in metus erat. Morbi eget ex dolor. Aenean tellus turpis, suscipit eu eros vel, ornare feugiat nibh. Suspendisse gravida nunc sem. Cras egestas vestibulum sem at convallis. Nunc eu cursus massa, sed aliquam libero. Sed placerat consequat suscipit. In
et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta quis purus non, euismod varius sem. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper turpis, ac auctor elit.
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus. Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo, at scelerisque ante. Nullam augue leo, cursus vitae mattis
eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a egestas eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat. Integer nec sapien felis. Aliquam bibendum egestas aliquet.
Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id mattis enim. Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse condimentum orci id diam hendrerit, eu laoreet sem pharetra.
Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante. Sed non leo urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur nec ante aliquet, lacinia risus
ac, tristique ipsum. Nam porttitor sed orci nec volutpat. Etiam finibus enim felis, at lacinia dui tempor at. Sed sem nulla, feugiat sed imperdiet quis, imperdiet nec felis. Nullam eget suscipit tortor. Suspendisse maximus nec sapien id placerat. Cras
ullamcorper enim quis blandit sodales. Fusce ullamcorper turpis libero, quis facilisis arcu condimentum sit amet. Etiam vitae luctus turpis, sed maximus nisl. Maecenas cursus tellus mattis eros placerat pulvinar. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam sit amet enim dolor. Ut et nisi quis urna congue rutrum. Phasellus mattis nulla eget neque dapibus, mattis mollis elit consequat. Nulla facilisi. Nullam ut nulla eu augue luctus viverra. Proin dictum
rhoncus finibus. Nulla sed luctus libero, eget sollicitudin purus. Ut pharetra quis neque vel vehicula. Curabitur fermentum, nibh ac efficitur fringilla, libero augue tempus dolor, in vehicula odio sem in felis. In eu feugiat dui. Aenean est elit, pulvinar
sit amet pretium ut, vestibulum non felis. In ullamcorper ullamcorper erat, a aliquam urna finibus et. Curabitur lobortis dapibus aliquam. Phasellus fringilla augue eget dui condimentum, ac ultricies ligula sodales. Aenean et nisi ut ante maximus porta.
Cras sollicitudin blandit purus, eget varius dui. Donec in metus erat. Morbi eget ex dolor. Aenean tellus turpis, suscipit eu eros vel, ornare feugiat nibh. Suspendisse gravida nunc sem. Cras egestas vestibulum sem at convallis. Nunc eu cursus massa,
sed aliquam libero. Sed placerat consequat suscipit. In et diam in mi auctor viverra vel commodo tortor. Suspendisse at magna diam. Curabitur eu sapien in nibh consequat ultricies vitae eget nulla. Nunc justo enim, porta quis purus non, euismod varius
sem. Aenean condimentum ullamcorper turpis, ac auctor elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vel semper tellus. Etiam condimentum, felis ut tincidunt venenatis, diam enim rhoncus neque, nec varius ante nulla et tellus. Vestibulum vel auctor leo,
at scelerisque ante. Nullam augue leo, cursus vitae mattis eget, euismod sit amet leo. Integer at commodo purus, a egestas eros. Phasellus a risus ac orci suscipit luctus at iaculis mauris. Fusce et est dui. Aenean a euismod nibh, sit amet vulputate erat.
Integer nec sapien felis. Aliquam bibendum egestas aliquet. Nunc tincidunt sapien sed odio mattis pulvinar id mattis enim. Nam interdum mattis enim, blandit interdum elit auctor in. Nulla quis nisl finibus, venenatis risus vel, rhoncus turpis. Suspendisse
condimentum orci id diam hendrerit, eu laoreet sem pharetra. Sed nec pharetra diam. Vivamus vel massa ante. Sed non leo urna. Proin et commodo magna. Vivamus sed est sollicitudin, egestas quam ornare, vestibulum elit.
```

Comment: Thorough and well explained!

Comment: Stellar answer, that site with the formulas is a must have.

Answer (score 2):

```
var height = $(this).height();
var offset = $(this).offset().top;
var opacity = (height - homeTop + offset) / (height * .9);
$(this).css("opacity", opacity);
```

Try something "like" that. You may want to put whatever the height "modifier" is in a variable. I'm no math guru either.